# How to store specific retuned JSON data from laravel into a php array

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have the following JSON object returned from Laravel query:

Laravel code:

```
$users = DB::table('orders')
    ->where('custid','=', $cid)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get();



[{"id":37,"date":"2016-11-30 19:16:30","status":"Processing","prodid":"23","custid":"46","created_at":"2016-11-30 19:16:30","updated_at":"2016-11-30 19:16:30"},
{"id":36,"date":"2016-11-30 18:59:29","status":"Processing","prodid":"23","custid":"46","created_at":"2016-11-30 18:59:29","updated_at":"2016-11-30 18:59:29"}]
```

I want to store the 'id' of each entry to a php array. I tried the following:

```
JSON_decode($users,TRUE);
```

To decode the JSON into a PHP associative array but I keep getting error 500. 
Any work arounds?

Comment: Can you provide the associated log?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON_decode($users[0],TRUE);`?

Comment: @Wistar Where can I find the log? I am hosted on EC2

Comment: @Arihent in your laravel folder `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @Wistar Tried JSON_decode($users[0],TRUE); still no luck. Looking into the logs now

Comment: How are you getting the JSON from Laravel? You may well be able to get it as an array to begin with.

Comment: @Wistar I don't see any logs for today's date in the file

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just added code for Laravel

Comment: If you `dd($users)` what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The builder's `get` method [returns a collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#collections), which has a [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray) method. You can use the [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) method to get just the id, if that's all you need.

```
$users = DB::table('orders')
    ->select('id')
    ->where('custid','=', $cid)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code snippet and it worked fine.

```
$data = json_decode(json_encode((array) $users), true);
```